# Snakes on a Plane! 2

Tags: grid-deduction

<sub>*An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1). Inspired by the title of [this xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/107/).*</sub>

---

Snakes ... on a plane ... again ...

This time 2 specimens of a huge unknown type of snakes swallowed a part of the passengers on a plane. Luckily the plane was able to land and all victims were rescued.

Unfortunately the rescue got a bit messy, and now you have to reconstruct the exact position of the 2 snakes at the moment of the landing for the FAA, based on witness statements.

[image: puzzle]

- The markings inside the plane show the ends of both snakes (one red and one yellow).
- The numbers on the sides show the number of squares in a row or column occupied by the corresponding snake.

You have also some additional information about the snake behavior from a local expert:

- All parts of a snake must be connected vertically or horizontally.
- Snakes don't branch.
- A snake doesn't cross or touch itself or the other snake (not even diagonally).

> **Disclaimer:** No snakes were harmed during the creation of this puzzle. Both specimen are securely stowed away on a train to their new home.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Answer

> [image]

## Step-by-step solution

> **NOTE: There is a slight error in the red snake, because I miscounted the 13. I'm too lazy to remake these images, so these won't be corrected, sorry.**
>  [image]
>  Start of puzzle. Top row is entirely occupied by red. The yellow snake can't turn left or right and must go down 5 rows due to the 1 clues:
>  [image]
>  Due to snake restrictions we must get to here.
>  [image]
>  More deductions on the red snake due to row clues.
>  [image]
>  And now, column clues, leveraging the fact that the 1 numbers don't permit turning around. This lets us fill the 17 row.
>  [image]
>  Now we must fill the rest of the 13 row:
>  **There are actually 14 squares now. Instead of finishing the row to the end, it should go downwards. We can see this by the 3 column at the end, in conjunction with the 2 row.**
>  [image]
>  And then they must go down, filling the side columns:
>  [image]
>  Red snake complete.
>  [image]
>  Yellow snake's east end can also use column clues with 1 numbers to get some progress:
>  [image]
>  We also can see that the leftmost yellow column can be entirely filled too:
>  [image]
>  This gets us some more progress, this time using 2 numbers similarly to 1 numbers earlier since we now have 2 ends to keep track of:
>  [image]
>  First very minor lookahead: if the three results in the top track going straight, we are going to collide into the red snake later on. So let's not.
>  [image]
>  Some more forced snake extension. Also, started on the tail of the airplane using nonogram logic (it must be in one piece due to the 2 above it).
>  [image]
>  9 in the 3rd row above the wings means that the top end of the left snake is filled up. So it turns up and connects to the real top end:
>  [image]
>  Actually this is how the 9 resolves as the other columns are already filled.
>  [image]
>  Now they go up...
>  [image]
>  Real east end heads straight as the 4 column is done now. The bottom ends must turn inward at least once.
>  [image]
>  There are two ways that the 9 in the 2nd row up in the wings can resolve. This is the wrong way:
>  [image]
>  This is the right way.
>  [image]
>   Now we look at the 18 in the 1st row up in the wings. Similarly if the east end went left once more, we encounter the same contradiction with the 5 column, so we should instead let the west end go right once. Now extend them both:
>  [image]
>  Oh right yeah that 5 column is already full. So is the 7 column. Therefore:
>  [image]
>  10 column isn't filled yet, but the left 14 column is. Right 14 column isn't filled yet. Hence to resolve and finish the puzzle:
>  [image]

Comment: I am truly impressed at how little brute forcing you needed to use

Comment: There is a minor mistake at the right side of the red snake.